# Managing & reporting Loans or Microloans to org from individuals?

Tags: wordpress, extension

Our organization accepts loans of $1000 or more from individuals and repays them incrementally with interest. What would it take to integrate the management, tracking and repayment of these loans with our existing WordPress-deployed CiviCRM system and data?

A few things to keep in mind:

- Each loan should be tied to either an Individual or to an Organization
- After our org (manually) accepts a loan offer, lender should be able to transfer funds to our merchant account via credit card or bank card
- Payments (by check) to lender would be entered manually by user
- Basic columns should include user_unique_id, Loan ID, Interest rate, Term, Creation date, Principle and Current balance
- Each Loan ID should be tied to a record of payments that includes date, check number and any other transaction-specific data for each payment

Is anyone else using Civi to manage incoming loans, and if so, how're you doing this? Or, is anyone interested in developing a new extension (i.e. Loans Component)? What might that cost?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Custom Contribution fields (on a per 'Contribution Type' if necessary) hence if you need fields that show Interest Rate etc you can do this via the UI.

I am unclear if you need the user_unique_id since the civi 'internal id' might do the required. Ditto for 'creation date' etc as these might be data that core civicrm handles anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Pete. To clarify my question, the functionality not already in Civi core would at least deduct new payments from loan principle (modify Contributions to work in reverse?), calculate and add interest to principle over time, allow for payment frequency options (annual, quarterly, monthly or custom), and calculate scheduled payments to lenders based on current balance and number of months remaining in term. Also, lenders should be able to make a Loan Offer, which org must manually accept or decline. If Loan Offer accepted, lender can initiate Loan via contribution page.

Comment: Yes I don't doubt you have some significant coding to do. Other thing to think about would be using Pledges in some way since that gives you the ability to set an amount and then chip bits off it as repayments come in - basically treat pledges in reverse?

Comment: Oh - and to answer your question. We would be interested to work on such an extension and would be happy to provide an estimate. Can you ping me directly peter.davis at fuzion.co.nz

Comment: We're working on a loan management system for an organisation at the moment. We've got phase 1 released, which deals with loan setups including advanced payment holiday calcs etc. If you'd like to join the project I can check with the client if they'd be happy for us to share and publish the code?